# Docker volume create outside of docker "internal" directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, docker-volume

I'm trying to specify the location where a volume is created.

I'm using:

```
# The following doesn't work, it will still bind to docker internal directory 
docker volume create \ 
   --driver local \
   --opt device=/var/foo/bar/ \
   --name postgres_volume1
```

My env:
Linux version 4.4.0-62-generic (buildd@lcy01-30) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017

Docker version 17.09.0-ce.

Answer (score 1):

The `local` volume plugin doesn't support specifying the location.

Use [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/) or a [custom volume plugin](https://hub.docker.com/r/cwspear/docker-local-persist-volume-plugin/) that supports specifying a location.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are creating the volume. So it will bind to docker internal directory. If you run the command :

```
docker volume inspect <volume-name>
```

It will show the actual mount point. If you want to change the location of volume, you don't have to create a volume using `create` command.
Here the [syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume) and all the details you should know about volume